# Why doesn't calling this Javascript/jQuery function work

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have put this at the top of my page (but within the `body` tag).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayNumberBounds(numberElement, number){
alert("it works");
  $(numberElement).before("<input type='text' size='6' id='lower' value='"+number+"' class='lt'/> &lt; ");
  $(numberElement).after(" &gt; <input type='text' size='6' id='upper' value='"+number+"' class='gt'/>");
}
</script>
```

and I have this further down (it's part of a template)

---- Edit ----

The way the code displays on the page is

.... some JavaScript/HTML here ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayNumberBounds(numberElement, number){
alert("it works");
        $(numberElement).before("<input type='text' size='6' id='lower' value='"+number+"' class='lt'/> &lt; ");
        $(numberElement).after(" &gt; <input type='text' size='6' id='upper' value='"+number+"' class='gt'/>");
}
</script>
```

.... more code here ...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".number-value").click(function() {
  displayNumberBounds(this,0);
  });
});
</script>
```

0

... a loop iterates, thus giving the second value ...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".number-value").click(function() {
    displayNumberBounds(this,0);
});
```

});
    
    0

```
 <script>
$(".number-value").click(function() {
  displayNumberBounds(this,<%=number%>);
});
</script>
<span class="number-value" value="<%=number%>">
  <%=number%>
</span>
```

Not sure if the extra info helps.

---------- end edit ---------

When I click the value that is printed by `<%=number%>` I get the expected result for the first `.number-value` item that is on the page but not for subsequent ones. I don't understand this.

Comment: Have you check that jQuery is loaded? Wrap your code into '$(document).ready(function() { //your stuff here }'

Comment: Yes, because I am using it elsewhere. PeeHaa suggested the same thing, I've made a comment about it.

Comment: The final verdict is that I was just being dumb. I put the .click() code into the <head></head> part of the page within <script>$(document).ready ... </script> and changed $(this).data("value") to $(this).attr("value")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-binding quite a bit, (`n` times), a better approach would be something like a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), for example your template would look like this:

```
<span class="number-value" data-value="<%=number%>">
  <%=number%>
</span>
```

Then *once* at the top of your page, bind to all of those, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".number-value").click(function() {
       var number = $(this).data("value");
       $(this).before("<input type='text' size='6' id='lower' value='"+number+"' class='lt'/> &lt; ")
              .after(" &gt; <input type='text' size='6' id='upper' value='"+number+"' class='gt'/>");
    });
});
</script>
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GaDVK/).

Or, it would be invalid HTML but use your *current* attribute, via `.attr("value")`.  *Or*, if the text always matches up you could just use `$.trim($(this).text())` instead, with no attribute.

Comment: Thanks Nick, for some reason it's still not working. Must be something to do with the rest of my code. I'll try and make a really simple version and then build it up.

Comment: @Ankur - check your error console, it sounds like something else is erroring out before this runs...

Comment: Can't see anything in Firebug's console window, I'm pretty sure I'll get it, if not I'll repost the more generic version I'm doing now.

Comment: I've setup a simpler version and that works, so it must be an issue in the rest of the code.

Comment: @Ankur - do you have a link to the page? I can take a quick look.

Comment: @Nick - I managed to sort it out ... your code worked fine :) actually what you said about the re-binding turned out to be correct.

Comment: ... although in the sense that I had already 'bound' in the <head> section and doing it again in the <body> section must have been the problem ... (hopefully that makes sense)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're trying to bind the click element when the element isn't loaded yet.

Can you try this please.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".number-value").click(function() {
        displayNumberBounds(this,$(this).html());
    });
});
</script>
```

Check out this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WS7Ha/

May I also suggest to you to move all Javascript to a separate .js file for maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Basically neither of the two instances where a class="number-value" item is displayed call the displayNumberBounds() method. Previously the first one on the page did, but at least now the behaviour is consistent

Comment: @PeeHaa thanks for your help. unfortunately it's not doing what I need it to. This code is generated based on some other conditional factors, so it's all nested in a number of templates. I will strip away everything unecessary and try and build up a non-dynamic version first. Thanks for your help. You gave me some good ideas.

Comment: @Ankur: If you need more help just setup a new jsFiddle and tell what's not working and I'll review / fix you code

Comment: @PeeHaa - your fiddle and posted code don't match...for example where does `number` come from in your code above?